# LinqToSql .Contains and nvarchar vs varchar parameters -> index conversion plan

Tags: linq-to-sql, orm

I have a just one table mapped in a datacontext.  Here's the property and attribute on the column of interest:

```
[Column(Storage="_CustomerNumber", DbType="VarChar(25)")]
public string CustomerNumber
{
```

This column is, in fact, a varchar(25) and has an index.

I've got some simple code:

```
DataClasses1DataContext myDC = new DataClasses1DataContext();
myDC.Log = Console.Out;

List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "111", "222", "333" };
myDC.Customers
    .Where(c => myList.Contains(c.CustomerNumber))
    .ToList();
```

Which generates this SQL text:

```
SELECT [t0].[CustomerNumber], [t0].[CustomerName]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CustomerNumber] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [111]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [222]
-- @p2: Input NVarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [333]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.8
```

Notice that the paramaters are nvarchar!

When this query hits the database, it generates a horrible plan which involves **converting the multi-million row index on CustomerNumber to nvarchar** before seeking within it.

I'm not allowed to change the table, but I can change the query and the dbml.  What can I do to get the data out without getting this index conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the way I solve this problem now-a-days.  This converts the parameters to the desired type and then runs the query.  It generates the same sql as originally generated, just with different parameter types.

```
DbCommand myCommand = myDataContext.GetCommand(query);

foreach (DbParameter dbParameter in myCommand.Parameters)
{
  if (dbParameter.DbType == System.Data.DbType.String)
  {
    dbParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.AnsiString;
  }
}    

myDataContext.Connection.Open();

System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
List<RecordType> result = myDataContext.Translate<RecordType>(reader).ToList();

myDataContext.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: This works, but there is one gotcha: the .Translate<T> method won't properly load related entities to T. (In otherwords, if you added .LoadsWith<TOther> on your context, and the TOther is related to T, then this will fail).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got as a possible work around.  I'm interested in seeing other solutions as well:

```
List<IQueryable<Customer>> myQueries = 
    myList.Select(s => myDC.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerNumber == s)).ToList();
IQueryable<Customers> myQuery = myQueries.First();
foreach(IQueryable<Customer> someQuery in myQueries.Skip(1))
{
    myQuery = myQuery.Concat(someQuery);
}
myQuery.ToList();
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t4].[CustomerNumber], [t4].[CustomerName]
FROM (
    SELECT [t2].[CustomerNumber], [t2].[CustomerName]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[CustomerNumber], [t0].[CustomerName]
        FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t0]
        WHERE [t0].[CustomerNumber] = @p0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [t1].[CustomerNumber], [t1].[CustomerName]
        FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[CustomerNumber] = @p1
        ) AS [t2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t3].[CustomerNumber], [t3].[CustomerName]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[CustomerNumber] = @p2
    ) AS [t4]
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [111]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [222]
-- @p2: Input VarChar (Size = 3; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [333]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.8
```

Answer (score 0):

For the project I'm working on, we have to use `ObjectContext` instead of `DbContext`, so I don't have ready access to `GetCommand()` or the `DbParameters`.  What I do is convert the query to a string, remove the NVARCHAR indicator in the query, then execute the query against the `ObjectContext`. Here's a verbose implementation for the example given:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "111", "222", "333" };

IQueryable<Customers> badQuery =  myDC.Customers
    .Where(c => myList.Contains(c.CustomerNumber));

string query = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)badQuery).ToTraceString();
query = query.Replace(",N'", ",'").Replace("(N'","('");

List<Customers> customers = myDC.ExecuteStoreQuery<Customers>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: That's LinqToEntities.  I'm using LinqToSql.  To the best of my knowledge, LinqToEntities does not have this query translation issue.