# LINQ to SQL Comparison Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have an issue with a linq to sql query - performance wise.
What i am trying to do, is find out if the elements of my collection of about 500 items (in a List) match db entries. Currently, this operation alone is taking about  300 seconds to complete! The database contains over a million rows and is bound to grow in the future so this level of performance so early on is simply unacceptable. Sample below:

```
var query = from item in db.DataTable.Where(x => x.date == suppliedDate)
            where inputList.Contains(item.name)
            select new { item.name};
```

Help!

edit:
Thanks a lot for all your suggstions! i just wanted to add a few additional observations as i've now been able to view the SQL output of my LINQ query (see below)

```
SELECT [t0].[name]
FROM [dw].[DataTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[name] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17)) AND ([t0].[date] = @p18)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Mark]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Owen]
-- @p2: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [James]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [John]
```

etc..

Is this making 500 separate hits on the DB? (As Ian suggested)? and is there any way i can imporve performance without having to resort to stored procedures or creating an additional table? (both options not really available to me right now). I've tried Geoff's suggestion and this brought my run time from 300 seconds to about 126 seconds - but that's still a lot especially considering how a db join would take less than 10 seconds at most.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you added any indexes to your database tables? Which indexes do you have?

Comment: Do the tables involved have appropriate indexes on the (x.date and item.name)?

Comment: There's an index on the "name" and "date" columns in my database - i read somewhere about how LINQ to SQL didn't support indexes though.. or is that just rubbish?

Comment: Stephen, sql supports indexes and linq generates sql so there's no truth in that. It can be sometimes tricky to get it to generate the sql you *expect* to take advantage of existing indexes but it's simple enough to view the sql generated and act accordingly.

Comment: @StephenA - That is only one query. Have you tried running your query in "Database Engine Tuning Advisor". Perhaps your indexes are not setup properly.

Comment: @StephenA - Do you mean milliseconds instead of seconds? I just did a test against a table with a million rows and 500 names and it executes in under a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Mark]
```

Is the column varchar?

If you check the execution plan for that query, you might see sql server converting the whole index to nvarchar (DOOOOOM!)

The fix is to convert the parameters to varchar.

---

You can get the command and reset the types of the parameters on it directly (to ansi-string in your case).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx

Then you might call ExecuteReader on that command, yielding a DbDataReader.  You can hand this DbDataReader to the Translate method of your datacontext, and it will give you the `IEnumerable<T>` that you'd expect from linq.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534213.aspx

I've posted the code to accomplish this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309991/linqtosql-contains-and-nvarchar-vs-varchar-parameters-index-conversion-plan/4147098#4147098)

Comment: Wow.. execution time down from 2 minutes to about 3 seconds. THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

You **may** be making 500 seperate requests to the database that with that query!

Firstly look at the sql that is running using the query profiler in sql server and see if Linq-to-sql is doing what you expect.

Comment: He is, but I think appropriate indexing will improve performance although I tend to prefer Shiv's answer

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var query = from item in db.DataTable
            where item.date == suppliedDate
            where inputList.Contains(item.name)
            select new { item.name};
```

You can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test your query and it will also show you what SQL is generated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that generates an sql query with an IN clause. The danger with that is you exceed the maximum number of sql parameters.

Comment: @Neil - Yes it does, but at 500 items he is still way behind the +-2000 sql limit

Comment: Agreed Geoff, I guess he will know whether he will ever come close to that limit. I encountered this problem for the first time with reported YSODs and had to re-architect my code on a broken site. I wish I had been more aware of this potential issue well in advance of that :-)

Comment: @Neil - Yes, definitely something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing will be quite a bit faster done in the database given the number of records you're dealing with.

I'd bulk insert the items in your list into a temp table and then do an inner join or intersect/except as need to get the result.

MSSQL 2008 also has a MERGE sql statement that is super fast that may help too. Doing something like this with over a billion records takes a few milliseconds providing your hardware can cope.

Which brings me to the othe thing :) hardware. Don't under estimate the hardware requirements, especially hard drive speed (typically a RAID 5/6 array comprised of anywhere between 6/12 spindles. for the kind of data you're dealing with if you need really good performance of your queires

Answer (score 1):

A faster way would be to avoid the linq code, you can save the inputList names into a sql table (using xml insert), then write a stored procedure that does the select and returns a dataset. Then In linq you can call that sp and extract the result.

Comment: Sending Xml into the database and storing it actually costs much more than the query, once the issue is addressed.