# Linq efficiency - How do I best query a database for a list of values?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Let us say I have a database of Terms and a list of strings, is this a good (efficient) idea?  It works smoothly, but I'm not sure it is scalable or the most efficient.

```
var results =
            from t in Terms
            join x in Targets on t.Term equals x
            select t;
```

Here Terms is a database table with index table Term.  Targets is an IEnumerable of strings.  Terms might hold millions, Targets between 10-20 strings.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it need to be fast? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Yeah, I'd test it and see how it's performing.  You can do all kinds of optimization (indexes, persistent views, caching, etc) that may help depending on your configuration, but test first, then optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately what matters, as far as efficiency is concerned, is if the query that is executed against the database is efficient.  To see this, you can either use SQL Profiler or find an application that will show you SQL generated by linq-to-sql.

If you use SQL Profiler, be sure to have it look for stored procedures, as Linq-to-sql uses the exec_sql procedure to execute queries.

Comment: This should help: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/18/how-to-use-profiler-with-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx

Comment: Not necessarily - this is likely to be a very efficient query, but return many more results than are necessary resulting in reduced performance because of network latency/capacity.  The most efficient option here depends on the relative size of the Terms and Targets sets.

Comment: Good point.  A where clause to limit this query is probably in order. :)

Comment: Joel, Terms will be in the millions (Term will be indexed), Targets is 10-20.  Just want to make sure I don't end up asking the database for millions... presumably Linq should do the right thing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Lol, seems like I should just test this eh?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to join two tables on one key, as in your example, there's no other way to express it than an actual join. What you have is as efficient as it CAN get.

However, change the `select` to return only the fields you're interested in, and make sure you trim them, because sql databases like to return `char` fields with trailing spaces, and they take time to process and transfer across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I didn't know you could join a local collection in like that.  Perhaps that's a .Net 4.0 feature?

I have frequently issued queries like this:

```
IQueryable<Term> query =
  from t in Terms 
  where Targets.Contains(t.Term)
  select t;
```

There's a few caveats.

- The variable x must be a `List<string>` reference.  The variable x may not be an `IList<string>` reference.
- Each string in the list is translated into a sql parameter.  While linq to sql will happily translate many thousands of strings into parameters (I've seen 50k parameters), Sql Server will only accept ~2100.  If you exceed this limit, you'll get a sql exception.
- [nvarchar vs varchar indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309991/linqtosql-contains-and-nvarchar-vs-varchar-parameters-index-conversion-plan).